# Check if multiple events are over

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm developing a modular application in jQuery.
Every module has an event handler for custom event "Save_special" like this:

```
$(document).on('save_special', function () {
    bind_contact_save();
});
```

I want a function to fire after event is done. Normally I would simply use a callback, but I have dozens of such event handlers in my code so callback method is impossible here. Anyone got any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

You could override the existing save function and add the callback into that, so you don't need to modify the existing code...

```
// keep a reference to the original save function
var _bind_contact_save = bind_contact_save;

// override the original function so this gets called instead
function bind_contact_save() {
    // call the original function
    _bind_contact_save();
    callback();
}
```

Anywhere in your code that calls `bind_contact_save()` will now fire the new version that will also trigger the callback function.